# optimal distinct element choice for each row in 2d matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Suppose we have three workers Bob, Jack & Hank. Given below are the tasks they can do in a day. How to optimally assign tasks so that each task gets done and all workers are put to some work.

Bob: car_wash, dusting, cooking

Jack: car_wash

Hank: dusting, car_wash

So for above example, bob gets assigned to do cooking, jack is assigned car_wash and Hank is assigned dusting.

What algorithm can be applied to solve this optimally? Brute force approach?

Comment: Are you looking for a perfect bipartite matching? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/

Comment: @ruakh will go through it, looks promising. Thanks

Comment: Will the number of workers always equal the number of jobs? Can a worker take on more than one job? how many? Can a job be worked on by more than one worker? How many?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your initial question.
Of which, there appears to be more than one correct answer.

Traverse each row, *m*, and subsequently each element, *a*.
For each, traverse the remaining rows, *mn*, or *m + 1*.
Compare each element, *b* with *a*, implying *f*.
Upon exiting the *mn* traversal, assign the value where *f* is *false*.

```java
String[][] A = {{"frt", "lkm", "pol"}, {"frt", "frt", "frt"}, {"lkm", "nhg", "qwe"}};
int m, mn, n;
String[] B = new String[n = A.length];
boolean f;
for (m = 0; m < n; m++)
    for (String a : A[m]) {
        f = false;
        for (mn = m + 1; mn < n; mn++) {
            for (String b : A[mn])
                if (a.equals(b)) {
                    f = true;
                    break;
                }
            if (f) break;
        }
        if (!f) B[m] = a;
    }
```

Output

```
[pol, frt, qwe]
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have M possible jobs, and N workers each able to do a subset of the possible jobs.  The problem is to find a job assignment for all workers such that each worker is assigned to a different job.

A way to approach this problem that mimics how *[constraint programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming)* works is to sequentially try job assignments until a satisfying assignment is found.  The general idea from constraint programming being that we virtually start with a space of all possible combinations, valid and invalid, and proceed by discarding invalid combinations rather than searching for the valid ones.

I am not a Java programmer and implementing this, especially with some generality, would be a lot of work anyway, so I am just going to show the equivalent of an execution trace:

```
A: car_wash, dusting, cooking
B: car_wash
C: dusting, car_wash

- A = car_wash
- B = car_wash : CONFLICT => try next B
- B = EMPTY  : IMPOSSIBLE => try next A
- A = dusting
- B = car_wash
- C = dusting  : CONFLICT => try next C
- C = car_wash : CONFLICT => try next C
- C = EMPTY  : IMPOSSIBLE => try next B
- B = EMPTY  : IMPOSSIBLE => try next A
- A = cooking
- B = car_wash
- C = dusting.
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this up as a graph theory problem.

We'll make a digraph:

- Nodes: Source, Sink, 1 per worker, 1 per job
- Arcs: from the source to every worker, from every job to the sink, and from each worker to all the jobs that worker can do.

Run the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm in O(max_flow + |Arcs|).